# Tallying number of unique occurrences on an integer field in R?

Tags: r

Here's some data that I'm working with:

```
tournament  round   player      holeocc
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     2
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     3
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     4
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     5
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     5
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     6
Masters     1   Tiger Woods     18
Masters     2   Tiger Woods     8
Masters     2   Tiger Woods     9
Masters     2   Tiger Woods     10
Masters     3   Tiger Woods     1
Masters     3   Tiger Woods     4
Masters     3   Tiger Woods     4
Masters     3   Tiger Woods     17
Masters     1   Mark O'Meara    1
```

I'm trying to count number of occurences of an event each round, but only once per hole, so hole 5 in round 1 and hole 4 in round 3.

I should end up with data that looks like this:

```
 player         tournament    round    num_of_occurences    
 Tiger Woods    Masters       1        6
 Tiger Woods    Masters       2        3
 Tiger Woods    Masters       3        3
 Mark O'Meara   Masters       1        1
```

Theoretically, this should be straightforward, I would just do something that looks like this:

```
results <- df %>% 
group_by(player, tournament, round) %>%
summarize(num_of_occurences = tally(unique(holeocc))
```

The problem with this is that tally doesn't seem to work with integer fields -- I tried mutating the field to string as a workaround, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Why won't tally work in this fashion?  Is there another count-like function that will handle this request?

Comment: Maybe `nrow` or `length` would work?

Comment: What if you use `n_disctinct(holeocc)` instead of `tally(unique(holeocc))`?

Comment: `nrow` doesn't, but `length does.  also, `n_distinct(holeocc)` works.  One of you wanna put it in as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `length` to get the length of the vector with your events, which is the same as the number of events. In this case:

```
results <- df %>% group_by(player, tournament, round) %>% 
    summarize(num_of_occurences = length(unique(holeocc)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try if `df` is your `data.frame`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(numOccur=length(unique(holeocc))), by=.(player, tournament, round)]
```

Comment: This works -- I think @ajerneck has a tighter answers because they tweak the query I'm using and don't require installation of a new library, but until one of them puts up an answer I'll count this one.  Thanks!